# Is shoes is a serious GUI toolkit for ruby?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, shoes

Does someone create real desktop GUI application with shoes or is it just used for learning purposes? Can shoes be compared with qtruby or gtk for ruby?

Comment: Relatively vague question. I have no experience to judge Shoes toolkit and its support and perspective, only I can add Ruby-GNOME2 (http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/) find very mature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What, for you, would make a "real" application?

[Here's a comparison between Shoes and qtruby.](http://shoesrb.tumblr.com/post/1480014928/other-ruby-gui-toolkits-qtruby)

Comment: by real applications I mean those which are not created for learning purposes. so, what's your choice of GUI toolkit?

Comment: I don't have one, I haven't needed to create any cross-platform apps. But I've seen Shoes before and I don't see why it would be any less legitimate than others.

Comment: OK, thanks for your opinion, waiting for others

Comment: +1 Sometimes people get confused because of _why's funny tone for development in general, but he's the author of many important and production-ready gems (like `hpricot` for example)

Comment: the link rotted, unfortunately

Comment: @feralin Yep, and unfortunately I can't find a cached version anywhere... :(

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is a serious toolkit and it is being developed all the time though slowly.
Now you can even use a shoes "clone" as a gem e.g. [green shoes](https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes)

Answer (score 3):

Shoes rocks...  greenShoes is a nice combination of gtk and Shoes.  you can definitely make "real desktop applications" with it.  there's a bit of a learning curve, as with any toolkit... but what really helps is that there is a strong community with great advice - fool around with it some, and get yourself onto the mailing list with questions/comments/advice/code - http://librelist.com/browser/shoes/  -  http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/shoes-forum-[ruby-gui]-849302/

here's the manual: 
shoesrb.com/manual/Hello.html

some great examples:
shoes-tutorial-note.heroku.com/

some more examples:
github.com/lljk/shoes-stuff

- jk